# How to correct "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" issues from I/O Kit?

Tags: objective-c, macos, iokit

I am running OSX Lion and would like to register for sleep notifications using I/O Kit as referenced [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1340/_index.html).

When I compile the code, I get `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` for the following symbols `IOAllowPowerChange`, `IORegisterForSystemPower` and `IONotificationPortGetRunLoopSource`.

I searched in Apple's documentation and they are all public functions. Any suggestions as to why I am getting those issues?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to link to the IOKit.framework

Comment: @jibat100. I've verified that I don't have a link problem since I am using `IOPMSchedulePowerEvent`, which is in the same header as `IOAllowPowerChange` and the other 2 functions I mentioned.

Comment: If you're not including the IOKit framework in your project then that's definitely your problem. If you are, then for some reason it's not the right architecture (not 64bits or ARM most likely). That or the IOKit requires additional frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why it matters but if I call any of the I/O kit's functions within a static function, the compiler will not report a problem, but if I don't use a static function I get an error.

Comment: It is an answer because it removed the errors and allows me to compile. I just don't understand why this resolved the error issue.

Comment: I think your question should therefore be, when I use IOKit methods in a static function, like this, I get compilation errors, why's that?

Comment: I discovered this after I asked this question.

Comment: New question is doing well! :)